# relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist in Rails 3.0.3 cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cucumber, delayed-job

I am running a Rails 3.0.3 with Postgres 9.0.1 and delayed_job 2.1.1. I configured delayed_job for Solr reindexing on an after_save callback which works great in development. When running cucumber tests for the model in question's create method, I get:

(::) failed steps (::)

PGError: ERROR:  relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
./app/controllers/admin/items_controller.rb:11:in `create'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:29
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in`with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:28:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/admin/item_create.feature:20:in`And I press "Create"'

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Having the same error, how did you solve it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you haven't run migrations on the test database.

Comment: Why doesn't this happen automatically?

Answer (score 5):

i.e. you should run `rake db:test:clone`

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000 RAILS_ENV=test
```